# Autofill a SharePoint List...iMacro didn't work

Tags: jquery, python, vba, sharepoint-2010, spservices

At work, we use SharePoint 2010 to log in issues.  For my area, the values for about 16 fields do not change. Instead of selecting 16 values every time I log an issue, I would rather auto fill them. I like to dabble with coding.  I know some Python and C++.  Can you please recommend a way that I could set defaults and run a script from my desktop to auto fill the 16 values for my issues.  I would just like to update the fields that change. I tried to use iMacro in Firefox, but it doesn't work as the form has a dynamic id, and the macro stops as it can't find the form id that I used to record the macro.  Any feedback would be appreciated because filling the same information is driving me out of my mind.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to add a Content Editor WebPart (CEWP) to the NewForm.apsx (the input form) that contains JQuery to auto-fill a value for t those fields.  If you don't have a reference to JQuery in your environment, you'll have to add one.  see this: http://sympmarc.com/2011/05/03/adding-jquery-to-a-sharepoint-page-step-one-always/

In JQuery, the easiest way to lookup and set a SharePoint field is using the Title attribute, which will map the external name of the field. so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[title='MyField']").val("I Set This!"); 
}
```

If you haven't done it before, you cant to add script tags in the content editor webpart.  so stick the above inside

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

One other best practice note: It's better to put the javascript in a text file that your reference from the CEWP than to just put the script directly in the webpart.  It also makes it much easier to edit.